# How to retrieve single row if data exist or null if data is not exist - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, select

This is my implementation in java for retrieving single row if data exist or null or empty if no data exist.

```
public SalesForecast isSalesForecastUser(String mobile) throws LookupException {
        SalesForecast salesForecast = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            salesForecast = (SalesForecast) session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast salesforcast where salesforcast.ppUserMobile ='" + mobile + "' ").list().get(0);
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            n.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException n) {
            n.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return salesForecast;
    }
```

This works fine if there is single or multiple row but throws this exception when there is no row matched:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: dont try to read the `lists as get(0) always` , we may not get the values while  records are empty so check if `salesForecast` is not null then return the `get(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in this way

```
    Query query = session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast salesforcast where
                                  salesforcast.ppUserMobile ='" + mobile + "' ");
    List results = query.list();
    if(results!=null){
        return results.get(0);
    } else{
        return null;
    }
```

In your current code

```
 salesForecast = (SalesForecast) session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast 
 salesforcast where salesforcast.ppUserMobile ='" + mobile + "' ").list() 
 // list will null if no result there, So you will get NullPoiterException
```

Comment: One correction. You should also check for list size before accessing any element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 try {   

        session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<SalesForeCast> salesForeCastList=session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast salesforcast where salesforcast.ppUserMobile ='" + mobile + "' ").list()  
           if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(salesForeCastList)){
             salesForeCast=(SalesForCast)salesForeCastList.get(0)
           } 
    }
```

Use [org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) which checks null as well as empty Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use

- [Query#setMaxResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29)

> salesForecast = (SalesForecast) session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast salesforcast
>
> where salesforcast.ppUserMobile ='" + mobile + "' ").setMaxResults(1);

Set the maximum number of rows to retrieve. If not set, there is no limit to the number of rows retrieved.

- [Query#uniqueResult](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29)

> salesForecast = (SalesForecast) session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast salesforcast
>
> where salesforcast.ppUserMobile ='" + mobile + "' ").uniqueResult();

Convenience method to return a **single instance** that matches the query, or **null if the query returns no results.**

---

### See also

It is good to use [Query#setParameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) to set the parameters

> salesForecast = (SalesForecast) session.createQuery(" from SalesForecast salesforcast
>
> where salesforcast.ppUserMobile = :mobile").setParameter("mobile", mobile).uniqueResult();